# Converting from nested functions into a chained functions

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm trying to convert this code I wrote into chained functions since I thought it would look cleaner.

```
let z =this.parkinglot.filter(val=>{
           let propArr =  Object.entries(val.spaces);
           let pass = propArr.some(w=>{
                let [key,value] = w;
                return (value > 0);
                })   
            return (pass===true); 
          })
```

My data structure is an array of objects that looks like this (Stored in an array called this.parkinglot)
[image]

When I attempt to rewrite this as chained function, I run into the problem of giving the proper input to my functions. Since I need the inner data I needed to use a map but now I have an 3 Layered Array.

Then I ran into the problem of how would I then give this data to filter properly.

```
let t = this.parkinglot.map(val => Object.entries(val.spaces))
  .some(w=>{
    console.log('aa',w);
      // let [key,value]=w
       //return (value > 0);
  })
  //.filter(z=>z>1)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text--put the actual structure as a copy-and-pasteable text block in the question. Otherwise, we have to type this in by hand. Also, I recommend just directly `return arr.some...` instead of `let pass = arr.some..; return pass===true`.

Comment: `some` returns boolean value so can't chain them like this

Comment: To make cleaner first thing you should remove here `(pass === true)`, instead just use `pass`

Comment: Use Object.values, not Object.entries

Comment: There really is no way to chain this

Comment: The function pretty much boils down to `this.parkinglot.filter(o => Object.values(o.spaces).some(e => e > 0));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest you can get to chaining it is a filter and inside a some. And since you only care about the values, use Object.values instead of entries.

```js
var data = [
  { level: 1, spaces : {a: 0, b:0, c: 0} },
  { level: 2, spaces : {a: 2, b:0, c: 0} },
  { level: 3, spaces : {a: 0, b:3, c: 0} },
  { level: 4, spaces : {a: 0, b:0, c: 10} },
  { level: 5, spaces : {a: 0, b:0, c: 0} },
]

const open = data.filter(level => Object.values(level.spaces).some(v => v))

console.log(open);
```

If you want the levels you can just add map() to the end

```
.filter(...).map(data => data.level)
```